# Find an Array in a two dimensional Array

Tags: javascript

Why does `indexOf` give -1 in this case:

```
   var q = ["a","b"];
   var matchables = [["a","b"],["c"]];
   matchables.indexOf(q);
```

How should I establish if the value stored in `q` can be found in `matchables`?

Answer (score 7):

Because `indexOf` uses `===` as the comparison flag.

`===` operating on non-primitives (like `Array`s) checks for if the `Objects` are identical. In JavaScript, `Objects` are only identical if they reference the same variable.

Try this to see what I mean (in console):

```
([])===([])
```

It returns `false` because they do not occupy the same space in memory.

You need to loop and use your own equality check for anything other than `true/false/string primitive/number primitive/null/undefined`

```
// Only checks single dimensional arrays with primitives as elements!
var shallowArrayEquality = function(a, b){
    if(!(a instanceOf Array) || !(b instanceof Array) || a.length !== b.length)
      return false;
    for(var ii=0; ii<a.length; ii++)
      if(a[ii]!==b[ii])
        return false;
    return true;
};

var multiDimensionalIndexOf = function(multi, single){
   for(var ii=0; ii<a.length; ii++)
      if(shallowArrayEquality(multi[ii], single) || multi[ii] === single)
        return ii;
   return -1;
};

multiDimensionalIndexOf(matchables, q); // returns 0
```

Comment: I'll add a quick function for checking **shallow** array equality

Comment: I use `ii` because it's easier to search against in code

Comment: `non-literals`? you probably mean non-primatives

Answer (score 3):

Because

```
["a","b"] === ["a","b"]
```

is `false`.

Comment: @What should I be doing to find ["a","b"] in matchables?

Comment: You will need to compare the elements piecewise; JavaScript does not have a way to test of two arrays have equivalent elements.

Comment: Everything they say is true, I added an example to mine to illustrate

Answer (score -1):

The way to get it to work would Be this:

```
var q = ["a", "b"];
var matchables = [q, ["c"]];
matchables.indexOf(q);
```

Comment: Does not answer question

Comment: @This is not how I wish to solve this problem. I'm interested in finding by value, not reference.